# unexpected end of file error in ffmpeg libavutils/common.h while compiling

Tags: ffmpeg

I am compiling following simple code in ffmpeg.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

void main()
{

    av_register_all();

}
```

all the ffmpeg headers i have included in project properties.
but i am getting the following error on compiling.

Error   1   error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found   dev\include\libavutil\common.h  87  1

Regards
Mayank

Answer (score 7):

Try define `__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS` before including those headers to see if problem can be solved.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
extern "C" {
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
};
```

See http://bigbang.waterlin.org/bang/using-ffmpeg-under-windows-visual-cpp-environment/

Regards zcy